# Unable to clear badge count from settings clear data in Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am facing issues for [badge plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/badge/) . 
From settings screen open application -> application info -> clear data 
After that on app icon badge count is still displayed.

```
 this.Subscription = Observable.interval(5000)
            .subscribe((val) => {
             this.badge.set(15);
            });
```

Plugin info

```
"dependencies": {
 "@ionic-native/badge": "^4.20.0",
"cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
}
```

ionic info

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (14 plugins total)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (
   NodeJS            : v8.11.2 
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Comment: put code snapshot

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari : Question updated

Comment: ionic3 or ionic4?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari : ionic3

Comment: when you set the badge , its maybe not considered like data on the app.

Comment: @Sam : Is there any way to considered that data on app ? suggest programmatically or solution please

Comment: I found in the plugin GitHub that badge is save on SharedPreference. I am sorry I don't know how resolve this.

Comment: @sam: still there is way to resolve it right ?

Comment: a simple way  is to check if ur data are clear  and after that u clear your badge but it work only if you launch app.

Comment: @sam it will not work if plugin has same issue

Comment: Maybe you can request the developper of the plugin to solve this .